# Why does R convert my entries in a level to NA?

Tags: r

I'm running GLMMs in R Studio as part of my data analysis and want to change the order of levels of a factor, using this code:

```
data$inf_cat <- factor(data$inf_cat, levels = "none","allo")
```

When I run this, R converts all of the "allo" entries to NA so when I run my GLMM, I get this error message:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I'm running the same code and GLMM on multiple datasets with the same structure and am only having this issue with one particular dataset. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? I've tried restarting R and re-importing the data but it hasn't worked.

Comment: `levels = "none","allo"` is a typo. That should be a vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to concatenate (`c(`) into a vector for the `levels`

```
data$inf_cat <- factor(data$inf_cat, levels = c("none","allo"))
```

otherwise, it will detect the `"allo"` as `labels` argument based on the order of occurence of parameters

> factor(x = character(), levels, labels = levels,
> exclude = NA, ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA)

and thus the "none" level will be changed to "allo" i.e. only a single level, which result in the error in contrasts where it requires 2 or more levels

Comment: Thanks so much, I completely missed that. My code is running fine now.